# How to change icon in menu with jquery selection

Tags: jquery, forms, input, selection

I have a language selector in my website and I want to change the icon of the main category with the flag when the user chose languages.

I have tried with this code, what's wrong? Any suggestions?

```js
$('div.country.cs-skin-elastic').on('click', function() {
    var myflag = $(this).data('flag');
    $('.countries').addClass(myflag);
})
```

```css
.cs-skin-elastic .cs-options li.flag-ita span {
    background-image: url(imgs/flag-ita.jpg);
    background-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contentp countries">  </div>                                    
    <form id="selections">
        <select class="country cs-skin-elastic" onchange="setLanguage()" name="countrySelect">
            <option value="null"></option>
            <option value="1" data-class="carrello">United States</option>
            <option value="13" data-flag="flag-ita">japan</option>
            <option value="10" data-flag="flag-ita">Germany</option>
        </select>
    </form>
```

Comment: First: the CSS rule is applied to a non-existant element (the span inside the li).
Second: the handler is applied to the div container, not the select, so it will not retrieve the correct language selection.

Comment: you have spelling mistake. you define  myflag variable and in addClss you used myFlag( capital F ).  . check my answer?  hope you declare  `setLanguage()` function? . remove `setLanguage()` from  attribute

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('div.country.cs-skin-elastic').on('change', function() {
    var myflag = $(this).data('flag');
    $('.countries').addClass(myFlag);
})
```

Comment: check this [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/6g697904/3/), select japan flag. also you will need to Handel to remove other classes.

Comment: Good, your code work on jsfiddle, but not on my site :( www.speedythemes.net, on the right nav i have just an icon. what's wrong?

Comment: Hello Yo.Meyers any news?